# Hover text for plot_geo function in plotly

Tags: r, plot, maps, plotly

I want to display the county name(subregion) and the population value(pop_cat) in hover.

Here's what i tried,

```
  library(tidyverse)
    library(plotly)

    df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bcdunbar/datasets/master/californiaPopulation.csv")

    cali <- map_data("county") %>%
      filter(region == 'california')

    pop <- df %>%
      group_by(County.Name) %>%
      summarise(Pop = sum(Population))

    pop$County.Name <- tolower(pop$County.Name) # matching string

    cali_pop <- merge(cali, pop, by.x = "subregion", by.y = "County.Name")

    cali_pop$pop_cat <- cut(cali_pop$Pop, breaks = c(seq(0, 11000000, by = 500000)), labels=1:22)

geo <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  showland = TRUE,
  landcolor = toRGB("gray95"),
  countrycolor = toRGB("gray80")
)

library(plotly)

geo <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  showland = TRUE,
  landcolor = toRGB("gray95"),
  countrycolor = toRGB("gray80")
)

p <- cali_pop %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  plot_geo(
    x = ~long, y = ~lat, color = ~pop_cat, colors = c('#ffeda0','#f03b20'),
    text = ~pop_cat, hoverinfo = 'text') %>%
  add_polygons(line = list(width = 0.4)) %>%
  add_polygons(
    fillcolor = 'transparent',
    line = list(color = 'black', width = 0.5),
    showlegend = FALSE, hoverinfo = 'none'
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title = "California Population by County",
    geo = geo)

p
```

Although I gave `text = ~pop_cat, hoverinfo = 'text'` in `plot_geo` function, it's not getting displayed when i hover on the plot. What should i do to display both `pop_cat` and `subregion` when i hover over the plot.

This is the plot that got generated. I have zoomed in the California region.

[image]

Comment: remove `hoverinfo = 'none'` and `hoverinfo = 'text'`. And you don't have `subregionìn in df.

Comment: @MLavoie Thanks. I am getting the `pop_cat` now. it's also showing the co-ordinates which i don't want to . Can you please suggest how to remove coordinates and add the county name instead.  The `subregion` is the county name. It happens here,           `cali <- map_data("county") %>%
      filter(region == 'california')`

Comment: see https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1152

Comment: @MLavoie Thanks!It worked :)

Comment: `text = ~pop_cat` seems to work again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some kind of bug in plotly. As said by @MLavoie you can find the solution here [https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1152](http://here)

I tried with the dev version of plotly and it's fixed. Also to display the county name and population i used  `text = ~paste(cali_pop$subregion, "<br />", cali_pop$pop_cat)`

Answer (score 2):

If you are still struggling with getting a hover even after installing from developer version, and if the error says something like `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plotly’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env): lazy-load database`, just refresh R-session, that worked for me.

@Harikrishnan for your answer. It helped me.